# Where should I store data for a C# application?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C#, at this moment writing an application. The need arose to save some data (a List object), to not store it in application memory.
Should I use usual SQL or do some better technologies exist? I think SQL is used, when there is a need to save some long-time data, but this data I check every 30-60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

SQLite is a good choice for internal storages. It gives you flexibility of database but it's small compared to traditional databases (e.g. MySQL) and requires zero-configuration. I'd use it if I had to read/write data regularly.

You might also want to take a look at [configuration files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0(v=vs.100).aspx) or [resource files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zabda143(v=vs.140).aspx)

Config file would be the best option if you need to load/save a small amount of data on startup/shutdown. You could store serialized list as follows:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="MyList" value="[contents of your serialized list]" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

A resource file is more advanced option compared to config file but probably it's not what you really need.

Comment: Agreed, you could preserve your variable values into local files or databases.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your application.
If you are doing some programs for fun or practicing/learning i would recommend you to start saving your data in XML files. Work with XMLs is something that all programmers has to know and its simplier than working with SQL since you need to install the DataBase Engine and if you are not familiar with SQL you are going to have some troubles.

There is also simplier ways to storage SQL data than the whole SQL Server engine, you can just use the LocalDb feature, i think Visual Studio provides it since the moment you install it and if it not, then you can check up your nuget package manager and download it.

Here is some information about localdb:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763(v=vs.110).aspx